# How come this value survives after the function returns?

Tags: c, memory

Title pretty much sums this up. How come it's possible that i can assign a locally created Point a (in the function ReadPoint()) into a variable that's in a different scope. Doesn't the locally created Point a gets 'popped' away along with stack of function readPoint() ? What exactly is going on ?

```
struct Point readPoint(void)
        {
            struct Point a;

                printf("x = ");
                scanf("%lf",&b.x);

                printf("y = ");
                scanf("%lf",&b.y);

            return a;
        }

        int main(int argc, char **argv) {
            Point test = readPoint();
            printPoint(test);
            return 0
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`struct`s are no different to primitive types in this regard.  It's exactly the same principle as:

```
int foo(void)
{
    int x = 5;
    return x;
}

int main(void)
{
    int y = foo();
    printf("%d\n", y);
}
```

The details of how this is achieved are implementation-dependent.  But usually, the return value (whether it's an `int` or a `struct`) is placed onto the stack by the called function, and then the caller then can then access that stack location.

Comment: So the function foo() will let it's caller into it's stack ?

Comment: @Scarlet: The stack is a contiguous area of memory; it doesn't belong to any particular function.  A particular compiler has a convention for where to place return values.

Comment: I didn't really mean it's stack by saying it's stack :) The part of memory on the stack that just happens to belong to foo() at this moment. Nevertheless, i finally get it, thanks a lot fine sir.

Answer (score 1):

The struct is "copied", byte by byte, into `test` in main...just like returning an `int` from a function and assigning it to a variable.

This, however, wouldn't happen if you were returning a pointer to the `struct` and the dereferencing it and assigning (or something similar).

Answer (score 1):

When returning, you'll create a copy of the object (with all members of the struct), but the local variable/object is still destroyed.

This will work unless you try to return a <s>reference or</s> pointer (in these cases your compiler should warn you about this stupid idea). This will work fine, unless you're trying to create a copy of something working with pointers.

In C++ this would include references too.

Answer (score 1):

This is because on return from *readPoint()* all structure values are copied to another locally defined structure *test*. Structure *a* does not survive.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is [structure assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29#Assignment). Almost all modern compilers can handle this.